# Laravel 5.1 - Polymorphic relationship for multiple columns

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, polymorphism

I have the next tables:

**images** (id, filename ...)

**pages** (title, slug ...)

**users** (username, email ...)

I created an **imageables** table to keep image relations

**image_id** /  **imageable_id** / **type** (Pages / Users etc.)

It works fine if I only need a single image(s) field per model.

But how should I proceed if I need for example **header_image** and **paragraph_image** in one page ?

If I want a single **header_image** / **paragraph_image** I can keep the field directly in the model (header_image_id, paragraph_image_id) but what if I have a top slider and a gallery for the article.. I will need 2 manyToMany relations.

Is it possible to keep all of them in the same **imageables** table ? Theoretically I will need another column for unicity (a field name for example.)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not creating your tables and relationships properly. In your case I would create 2 different tables: pages and images with a pivot table relationship.

1. Pages table: id, title, slug...
2. Images table: id, **type**, filename...
3. Pivot table (Images and Pages): page_id, image_id.

Then you can simple use the type column of the Images table to set the place where you want to put that image. You can set type equals to header or paragraph or slider...

```
$image = new Image;
$image->type= 'header';
$image->filename = 'yourimage.jpg';
...
$image->save();
```

In your view you can retrieve the image you want for your header, paragraph, slider like this:

```
$page->images()->where('type', 'header')->first();
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It works in this case but I am trying to avoid creating pivots for every model where I need images so I am trying to use polymorphic relations.

Comment: In that case you were right with your conclusion. Just create a Polymorphic relation table called Images with following columns: id, filename, type(header, slider, paragraph...), imageable_id (this will contain the id of the page or any other Model), imageable_type(this will contain the Model name). If you want to know how to create the Model check this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relations

Comment: I would prefer manyTomany polymorphic table with image_id / imageable_id - item id /  imageable_type - Model name / + a field name if I have multiple fields in the same model (slider, article images). I do not know if it is possible.

Comment: Maybe I am confuse or I understood it wrong but I think what you are describing is what I explained in the comment above and in my opinion it is the correct way for handling Polymorphic relation.

Comment: Well...I hold images in images table and polymorphism in imageable table (image_id / imageable_id / imageable_type and I need another field for multiple field support...this is what I want to achive but I`m not sure if it is possible)> I found something. I will test it. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3693

Comment: But you don´t need to have 2 different tables to complete this task. Just one images table would do the job as I mentioned in my last comments.